# How do I update MySQL 5.7 to the new MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-server, mysqlupgrade

How do I **update** to MySQL 8.0 from the default version (5.7)?

It's important for me for it to make an update and not re-install MySQL so all my data won't be corrupt.

There is not a lot of info regarding this issue since it was only released not long ago with [tons of awesome new features!](https://mysqlserverteam.com/whats-new-in-mysql-8-0-generally-available/)

[This is what I have found](https://blog.softhints.com/how-to-install-mysql-8-on-ubuntu-16-04/) that seems like it will only update and not destroy my data. I'm not going to proceed until I'm sure.

Comment: just make backup before update - mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql

Comment: I have 7 database with enormous amounts of data. Prefer not to do that in these conditions. @iliya.rudberg

Comment: Not backing up your data bases before an upgrade is foolish.

Comment: I didn't say my data isn't backed up. @P.Salmon

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html

Comment: "I'm not going to proceed until I'm sure." - Install 5.7 on a test server. Then upgrade to 8.0

Comment: Make sure that any upgrade is done on a test system (same OS, same current MySQL version, same MySQL databases, etc) so you can identify issues before you attempt any update, especially one jumping multiple major releases at once.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can find answer in mysql [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-upgrading).
It has full details about how to upgrade.
Make sure to back up data before upgrading.

There are tons of ways to upgrade in the docs.
The way i choose is to use APT Repository.

You should do the following things:

First, add the MySQL APT repository to your system's software repository list. The details in docs are a little abstract , i'll give a example:

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb
```

Then you'll get this:

[image]

press Enter when you choose mysql server ,then select mysql 8.0.Finally choose like this:

[image]

Once the repo has been added, update apt index and install mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Now if you don't get any error messages, you have already upgraded successfully.
You can confirm by:

```
apt policy mysql-server
```

You will get output like this:

```
$ apt policy mysql-server
  mysql-server:
      Installed: 8.0.13-1ubuntu18.04
      Candidate: 8.0.13-1ubuntu18.04
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 the command should be `apt-cache policy mysql-server` instead of `apt policy mysql-server`

Comment: For WSL you may need to run: curl -sL "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x8C718D3B5072E1F5" | sudo apt-key add

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore `Err:5 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
`

Comment: I think you may get help from this :https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387053/debian-9-apt-and-gpg-error-inrelease-the-following-signatures-were-inva  @Eugene van der Merwe

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe for me it worked well: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5

Comment: I also got the "Following signatures were invalid." error. Downloading the latest from the oracle site solved it. Ubuntu 18.04 for me.

Comment: This process worked for me after changing wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb to wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb

Comment: I want to upgrade mysql in ubuntu docker image, but with this method I'm getting error related to GUI, how do I skip the GUI configuration?

Comment: The newest version (November 2022) is https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb - if you are trying this in the future, get the link to the newest version from here https://repo.mysql.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use Mysql manual 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install

The sequence there is about the same, but it seems that the link to the settings file is changing.
I use
 https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have small appendix to the [helpful answer by 请叫我小马哥](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49963923/4314825).

My challenge was to update MySQL client from 5.7 to 8.0. I needed that because I got warnings when tried to export remote 8.0 database with client 5.7 and MySQL Workbench 6.3 at my ubuntu 18.04 machine. I did not have MySQL server installed and I did not intend to do it.

The install command was

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-community-client
```

The next step was to install MySQL Workbench Community 8.0 because 6.3 threw mysqldump version error when tried to export. I have done the instalation in lamer's way using ubuntu Software app. This probably saved me connection issues because I could at once apply required commands as detailed in the description:

```
sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service 
sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:ssh-keys
sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:cups-control
```

The last one did not work for me, so I skipped it:

```
sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:cups-control
```