# Upgrading mysql 5.7 to 8.0 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04, mysqlupgrade

I’m attempting to upgrade my mysql server from 5.7 to 8.0 on ubuntu but I am getting an error on the install. I followed the instructions in the comments here: [How do I update MySQL 5.7 to the new MySQL 8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963923/how-do-i-update-mysql-5-7-to-the-new-mysql-8-0)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here’s what I’ve done.

```
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.27-1_all.deb
 
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.27-1_all.deb
```

- selected "MySQL Server & Cluster"
- selected "mysql-8.0"
- selected “Ok"

```
sudo apt-get update
 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
  Reading package lists... Done 
  Building dependency tree 
  Reading state information... Done 
  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
  The following information may help to resolve the situation: 
 
  The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
    mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.35-1ubuntu23.04) but 5.7.37-1ubuntu18.04 is to be installed 
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 
 
apt policy mysql-server
  mysql-server: 
    Installed: (none) 
    Candidate: 8.0.35-1ubuntu23.04 
    Version table: 
      8.0.35-1ubuntu23.04 500 
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu lunar/mysql-8.0 amd64 Packages 
      8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500 
        500 http://iad-ad-3.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages 
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages 
      8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500 
        500 http://iad-ad-3.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```